# Wait for a subscribe method in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a method in a provider

```
getProfile() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.get(this.db_url + 'profile',{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

I'm calling the above method in another provider as

```
getProfile() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe((profile: any) => {
      this.profile = profile.user._id;
    },(err : any) => console.log(err))
  }
```

Here I want to stop the execution of the code until `this.profile = profile.user._id` this line is executed.In the same `provider` where I declare the `getProfile()` method, I have the http request as

```
let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    let selected = {
      address: home.address, 
      date: new Date(),
      id: this.profile // from the getProfile() file.
    }
```

`console.log(selected);`

The output for the `id` is `undefined`. I think there is an async here.

Comment: Can you give an example of code that would have to wait?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I don't know why you need this but Angular supports two-way data binding so you don't need to do that. Explain in more details

Comment: I have edited the question please look into it.

Answer (score 1):

put this code in a function like

```
setHeadres(){
 let headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
 let selected = {
  address: home.address, 
  date: new Date(),
  id: this.profile // from the getProfile() file.
 }
}
```

and call this function inside `getProfile()` function like below

```
getProfile() {
 this.authService.getProfile().subscribe((profile: any) => {
   this.profile = profile.user._id;
   this.setHeaders();
 },(err : any) => console.log(err))
}
```